# Máscara monetária para JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Tenho um campo `JTextField` que deverá receber do usuário um valor monetário. Gostaria de adicionar uma máscara a este campo para que o mesmo formate os valores inseridos da seguinte forma: 9.999,99.

Comment: Baixe esta biblioteca, facil e rapido
`http://tiagojavaprogramador.blogspot.com.br/p/minha-b.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O jeito mais facil, @Rodox, é utilizando a classe `MaskFormatter`.

Primeiramente vc cria uma instancia da classe `MaskFormatter` com um construtor neste formato:

```
MaskFormatter mascaraCampo = null;
try {
    mascaraCampo= new MaskFormatter("#.###,##");
}catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Após isso, é só preciso instanciar o `JFormattedTextField`, passando a mascara como parâmetro.

```
JFormattedTextField campoFormatado = new JFormattedTextField(mascaraCampo);
```

Exemplo Funcional:

```
public class Funcional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 310, 330);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);         
        MaskFormatter mascaraCampo = null;
        try {
            mascaraCampo = new MaskFormatter("#.###,##");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        JFormattedTextField campoFormatado = new JFormattedTextField(mascaraCampo);
        campoFormatado.setVisible(true);
        campoFormatado.setBounds(25, 25, 245, 30);
        frame.add(campoFormatado);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Após isso, é só preciso instanciar o seu JTextField, como um JFormattedTextField.`, Isso não é possivel pois são componentes completamente diferentes. Apesar do segundo herdaro primeiro, não é possivel usar um como se fosse outro.

Comment: O `JTextField` foi utilizado para identificar o `JFormattedTextField`. Observe os exemplos, em nenhum momento escrevi um `JTextField` recebendo uma instancia de `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: `instanciar o seu JTextField, como um JFormattedTextField` - isso aqui pode confundir usuários novatos, pois também da a entender isso, enfim, foi só um alerta, se não achar útil a dica, é direito seu.

Comment: Concordo que fica ambíguo, mas n foi minha primeira intenção. Acredito que está melhor estruturado agora.

Comment: Com certeza, ficou melho agora :D