# Formatação de JTextField com máscara de CPF

Tags: jtextfield

Alguém saberia me responder como deixo um campo `JTextField` com a máscara de CPF. Acho que tem como fazer isto setando um `Document` para o `JTextField`, porém não sei como fazer. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Observação: desejo utilizar um `JTextField` e não um `JFormatedTextField`.

Comment: Dá uma olhada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41083/m%C3%A1scara-monet%C3%A1ria-para-jtextfield

Comment: Está usando qual IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fbarros você pode fazer implementar a interface Document e setar no JTextField.

Sugiro que estenda a classe javax.swing.PlainDocument, então sobrescreva o método insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a).

Nesse método trate a String str. Ela é o que você deve tratar quais caracteres aceitos ou não. O valor dela é o que está sendo inserido no JTextField antes mesmo de ser exibido.

[Nesse link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0200__Document.htm) ([+ esse](http://www.guj.com.br/articles/29)) você encontra alguns exemplos de como criar um document para o JTextField com restrições de entrada.

**Nota:** Possivelmente terá que sobrescrever o método remove(int offset, int length) também;