# Formatar um textfield com estilo de moeda

Tags: java, java-8

Estou usando o NetBeans, e não consigo mostrar o valor formatado como moeda, por exemplo R$ 1.200,00. Quando digito no campo texto, os zeros não aparecem. Tenho um formulário com dois campos: Um para nome e outro pra salário. Nos dois, estou usando campo de texto para receber os dados, e um botão para exibir os dados em uma caixa de diálogo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma classe Chamada Funcionário, conforme código abaixo:

```
public class Funcionario {
public String nome;
public double salario;
}
```

Código do botão Exibir, conforme abaixo:

```
   private void btnExibirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Funcionario funcionario1 = new Funcionario(); 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    try
    {

        // Passa o conteúdo digitado para as variáveis
        funcionario1.nome = txtNome.getText();
        funcionario1.salario = (Double.parseDouble(txtSalario.getText()));            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n*** Resultado ***" + "\n" +
        "Nome : " + funcionario1.nome.toUpperCase() + "\n"+            
        "Salário. .......: " + df.format(funcionario1.salario));
        }
        catch(Exception erro)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, erro + "Verifique se Você deixou algum campo vazio !!!", "Erro na Entrada de Dados", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
}
```

Gostaria também de saber com o faço para testar se os campos estão vazios e se o campo salário é somente numérico.

Comment: Você quer que formate na medida em que se digite? Se for, não é dessa forma, e sim, usando mascara num campo tipo JFormattedTextField.

Comment: Eu me lembro de uma resposta de uma pergunta antiga sobre isso, máscaras para JFormatted [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41083/m%C3%A1scara-monet%C3%A1ria-para-jtextfield/41325#41325), Vê se te ajuda, @Montesuma.

Answer (score 1):

tenta isso para numeros, quando você faz o parse se o string não for um válido formato numérico o parse throw um NumberFormatException

```
try
{
    funcionario.salario = Double.parseDouble(txtSalario.getText().toString());
} 
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
     //msg de erro aqui 
}
```

já para valores monetário Java dispõe uma classe para fazer esse trabalho seria a NumberFormat.class

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(funcionario.salario));
```

aí troca no lugar do println usa o setText.

ps: código não foi testado , pergunta respondida pelo aplicativo do telefone

Comment: E como aplicar o double no código abaixo? Seria interessante você demonstrar a ligação dos dois trechos, que ficaram soltos entre si.

Comment: fiz pelo telefone , e só trocar o amount pela variable funcionario.salario , vou editar a resposta pra vc entender

Comment: Ok, consegui, muito grato. Gostaria de saber como faço usando um campo formatado jFormattedTextField1 tipo moeda, usando esta mascára ¤ #,##0.00, quando digite algu valor dentro do campo, ele me retorna uma mensagem de erro: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Neste exemplo estou usando um jTextField1.